# Template Microsoft Project with Scrum

Tags: scrum, ms-project, product-owner

I am a Product Owner.

Does anyone have a template/example of how to use Microsoft Project to manage Scrum? I need to know how to manage the backlog, handle sprints, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Project is generally not used for Scrum. This is because it uses the Gantt style visualisation with dependencies between work items. Scrum typically attempts to minimise dependencies and does not attempt to enforce an order of completing work.

You could use Project to indicate when the Scrum ceremonies take place (e.g. planning, retrospective and sprint review). You could even have a backlog in Project - just a series of work items with no associated start/finish date. Then when you plan for a sprint you could move these items under a sprint in Project.

But it is debatable whether this would provide any value.

Alternatively, you may want to consider tools that are designed to work with Scrum, like JIRA or Trello.

Comment: +1: Tools like MS Project are designed to manage to a date. In Scrum you're managing a backlog not a date. Trello is a free tool that you can get started with and then I suggest looking for "Agile Lifecycle Management" tools not "Project Tools" when doing web searches.